# Questions about cast shadows

Tags: light

is there a way to make the cast shadows of the sun light less dark?
Im working on an animated object that will have a cast shadow on a shite background, but right now the cast shadow is way to dark.

question 2
is there a way to use a HDRI as a light source but get rid of the cast shadows that is caused by the HDRI (lightpath maybe?)

Always grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use this setup for your object. (i assume your are using cycles)

blue is your object color, on the orange bsdf you can change the alpha to change the shadow darkness.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Chris, tried this but the cast shadows are still just as dark

Comment: Ok, provide your blend file - I will show you, that this setup works

Comment: II signed a NDA for this project so unfortunately I can't share the file but I can recreate a blend file with the same situation and send

Comment: never mind, though you meant that this node setup was meant for the object that the cast shadow falls on but figured out that its the object causing the shadow that should have the node setup, thank you for your help, really appreciate it!

Comment: You are welcome. Would be nice if you check the answer as right.

Comment: absolutely, I did check the answer